# Find the angle $x$ based on a trigonometric relationship.

Tags: trigonometry

Find the acute angle $x$ given that 
$\dfrac{\sin(x)}{\sin(110°-x)} = \dfrac{\sin(20°)\sin(40°)}{\sin(60°)\sin(30°)}.$

I reduced a geometric problem to this equation above and I've been trying to prove this for a while. Since there are two sines with variables inside my objective is transforming the right hand expression into something of the form $\dfrac{\sin(a)}{\sin(b)}$ where $a+b = 110°$ because it is well known that if $\dfrac{\sin(a)}{\sin(b)} = \dfrac{\sin(c)}{\sin(d)}$ with $a,b,c,d$ acute and $a+b = c+d < 180°$ then $a=c$ and $b=d$ but I've had no luck transforming the right hand side into that.

I would appreciate any way to solve it, but mostly an approach that does transform it to only a ratio of two sines in the right hand side as well.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities : here you can find some formulas which may help you (or not). Good luck!

Comment: I checked and I know most of the formulas that look applicable to this but I haven't been able to apply them in the correct ways yet.

Comment: What's your geometric problem? Maybe there is another method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of magic. The equation is equivalent to
$$\sin(x)\sin(30°)\sin(60°) = \sin(20°)\sin(40°)\sin(110°-x).$$
By [Morrie's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morrie%27s_law), $\displaystyle \sin(20°)\sin(40°)\sin(80°)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{8}.$ Hence if there is a unique solution with $0°<x<90°$, it should be $x=30°$ (remember that $\sin(30°)=1/2$ and $\sin(60°)=\sqrt{3}/2$).

You can be more rigorous and show that the above solution is unique.
Let $f(x)=\dfrac{\sin(x)}{\sin(110°-x)}$ then $f'(x)=\frac{\pi}{180°}\cdot\dfrac{\sin(110°)}{\sin^2(110°-x)}$ which is positive, so $f$ is strictly increasing!